# Accessing files in ibm bluemix java runtime

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Java runtime on Bluemix. I have pushed a standalone executable jar file to this runtime. The jar file also contains a properties file.

This needs to be accessed through a USER-DEFINED environment variable, as this properties file changes per environment.

I set a property called `ENV_PROPERTIES= /com/java/prod.properties`, so that the application picks up that properties file when it's running.

MY question: Is there a way in CF-based PaaS to refer to deployed files using environment variables in Bluemix?

Answer (score 1):

@prasanna-bableshwar

Yes, you can create a user-defined environment variable from the bluemix console.  See the section entitled "Adding user-defined environment variables"[1]:

[1]https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#app_env

Comment: yes I am aware of that. But can you use that variable to point to a file that you have deployed. and use it in your program?

Comment: how will u give the path to a file inside your jar? Do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

This part of the puzzle in my application is now resolved. Although for a java instance(for that matter any runtime) The root folder of your files always start with 'app' folder. so the path you will need to mention will start from one level inside this app folder. In my case the folder under 'app' was called java. So my user defined property read like this:
    `ENV_PROP = java/prod.properties`

Hope this helps